# Using gains subject to capital gains tax to pay down debt on real estate in an opportunity zone

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax

So I'm just learning about opportunity zones. Please keep that in mind as you read this because it likely contains incorrect assumptions.

**The scenario** - I have an investment I made, that appreciated rapidly over the last year and now I'm subject to a massive amount of taxes if I realize this gain.

**My solution** - I'd like to take these gains and put them into an opportunity zone in order to take advantage of the tax deferment benefits the federal government is offering.

**The problem** I'm trying to understand - If I have existing rental property real estate, under a loan, in an opportunity zone, can I use these funds to pay down that debt or does it have to be new investments? If I can't use it, could I possibly form a company specifically for this opportunity zone investment and sell my rental properties to that company so that on the books it appears that it's a new investment?

**Edit**
The investments subject to capital gains tax are a mix of long term and short term holdings from rent, stock sales, crypto currencies, and a sale of a rental property.

Comment: Could you clarify what investment is this? I wonder if real estate gains is different from, say, sale of stock (Short Term Capital Gain).

Comment: Well that's actually more complex than it might seem. I took cash from rent and put it into the stock market and crypto currencies all over a year ago. Those went up. Then I also sold one of my rental properties a couple months ago, put the proceeds into crypto and then that rocketed. Some are short term gains and some are long term gains.